# NodeJS PM2 - Programmatically restart process using PM2 API

Tags: node.js, process, restart, pm2

I want to programmatically restart a process using PM2 API in NodeJS. From their [docs](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/pm2-api/), I learned that you can do this by calling `pm2.restart(process, errback)`. Thing is that it is not said anywhere what type the `process` argument must be.
Does it have to be the name of the process? Or its PM2 process ID? Or a PM2 process object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did a quick test, name of the process should work, for example:

```
var pm2 = require('pm2');

pm2.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    process.exit(2);
  }

  pm2.restart('timer', function(err) {
    pm2.disconnect();   // Disconnects from PM2
    if (err) throw err
  });
});
```

Where `timer` is the name of the process started with pm2.